# Android Widget Collection View: how to get appWidgetId of calling widget from RemoteViewsFactory?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, android-appwidget-list

Is there any way to access the calling `appwidgetId` inside `RemoteViewsFactory`'s `getViewAt` method?  I have data persisted by `appWidgetId` and without access to `appWidgetId` it doesn't work.

Or, is there a pattern for multiple widgets backed by collection views?

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets#collections)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: figured this out; forgot to call Intent.setData();  doing this ensures you get a 2nd RemoteViewsFactory..

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same id for every widget, because I was missing the **Intent.setData()** line:

```
Intent remoteViewsServiceIntent = new Intent(context, RemoteViewsService.class);
remoteViewsServiceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
remoteViewsServiceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(remoteViewsServiceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_listview, remoteViewsServiceIntent);
```